# Django Admin for Multi-Table Inheritance Models

Tags: python, django

I've got the following models for a user set up using multi-table inheritance:

```
class MyBaseUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    # model fields....

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'


class SubUser(MyBaseUser):
    # model fields
```

Now in terminal, everything seems to be working as expected, when creating a `SubUser` it returns a `SubUser` instance and creates a `MyBaseUser` in the db. If I query the `MyBaseUser` class for the id of the created `SubUser` it returns and I can do `my_base_user_instance.subuser.<sub_user_field>` - all behaving as I'd expect.

How should I set up a `ModelAdmin` for the `SubUser` class though?

I've got:

```
@admin.register(SubUser)
class SubUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # fields...
```

but none of the `SubUser` instances are showing up, which I think makes sense given how the multi-table inheritance works, but how do I set up the admin to display/update the subclasses? I've not run into this before, thanks.

Comment: Did you set abstract = True on your MyBaseUser class?

Comment: No unfortunately it can’t be abstract due to existing users in the db

Comment: I assume the inheritance is `SubUser(MyBaseUser)`.

Comment: Yeah sorry! Have updated the question

Comment: My guess is you don't see it, because they share the verbose_name_plural and are in the same app. Override the verbose_name_plural for the SubUser model.

Comment: Interesting I hadn’t thought of that, thanks I’ll give it a go